# How to run raw mongodb commands from pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In a `mongo` command line I can run

```
db.my_collection.stats()
```

I need to get my collections stats from `Python` so I tried

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test_database

collection = db.test_collection

collection.stats()
```

But I get

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. 
If you meant to call the 'stats' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

This is because `pymongo` does not support this method. How do I send raw `mongoDB` commands to `mongo` through `Python`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()

db = client.test_database

print(db.command("collstats", "test_collection"))
```

Comment: for passing scale (since all sizes are given in bytes) you can do this: `db.command("collstats", "test_collection", scale=1024*1024)`. This will convert into MB. You can also also change it up as you like for KB, GB, etc. However, `avgObjSize` will always be in `bytes`.

Answer (score 4):

Approach 1 with [PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/):

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(host = "127.0.0.1", port = 27017)
db = client.test_database
db.command("dbstats") # prints database stats for "test_db"
db.command("collstats", "test_collection") # prints collection-level stats
```

This can be done with this approach in Django.

```
    from django.db import connections

    database_wrapper = connections['my_db_alias']
    eggs_collection = database_wrapper.get_collection('eggs')
    eggs_collection.find_and_modify(...)
```

From [django-mongodb-engine docs](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> django.db.connections is a dictionary-like object that holds all
>   database connections – that is, for MongoDB databases,
>   django_mongodb_engine.base.DatabaseWrapper instances.
>
> These instances can be used to get the PyMongo-level Connection,
>   Database and Collection objects.