# $push and $set in same update query with condition $cond pymongo mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo, mongodb-update

I'm trying to update my collection

For the single, object need to update the status and updated time.

Input object id as `id` new status as current `status`

Condition If the `new status` is different from the `status` in DB, then need to `$push` `new status` and `timestamp` into `activity_log` array.
And update the update the `updated_time` and `status` of the record.

If the `new status` and previous status is same then `updated_time` will be updated.

Is it possible to do that in pymongo using single update ?

```
collection.update({
        '_id': ObjectId(id),
    }, {
        '$cond': {
            'if': {
                'status': {
                    '$ne': current_status
                }
            },
            'then': {
                '$push': {
                    'activity_log': {
                        'status': current_status,
                        'changed_time': datetime.now()
                    }
                }
            },
            'else': None
        },
        '$set': {
            'status': current_status,
            'updated_time': datetime.now()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Please edit this question with 1) Sample doc , 2) Input , 3) Conditions to be applied & 4) result doc after update applied  !! Db version ?

Comment: Updated with the input and condition mongodb version is `MongoDB 4.2.5 Community`.

Comment: I have updated my answer, It is possible to do it in a single query, I have tried it on Mongo client the updated query is working, please check.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in a single query, From MongoDB 4.2 update query supports [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#update-method-agg-pipeline), You can do that as per below code

```
collection.update(
     {'_id': ObjectId(id)}, 
     [{'$set': {
            'status': current_status,
            'updated_time': datetime.now(),
            'activity_log':{
              '$cond': {
                'if': {'$ne': ['$status',current_status]},
                'then': {$concatArrays:['$activity_log',[
                          {
                           'status': current_status,
                           'changed_time': datetime.now()
                          }
                ]]},
                'else': '$activity_log'
            }
      }}}]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$cond` operator is not flow control like if-then-else, it is an expression that returns a value.

If you want to conditionally update a field based on the value of another field in the same document, you can use the pipeline form of update, assigning the field the result of the `$cond` expression.

```
collection.update(
     {'_id': ObjectId(id)}, 
     [{'$set': {
            'status': current_status,
            'updated_time': datetime.now(),
            'activity_log':{
              '$cond': {
                'if': {'$ne': ['$status',current_status]}
                'then': {$concatArrays:['$activity_log',[
                          {
                           'status': current_status,
                           'changed_time': datetime.now()
                          }
                ]]},
                'else': '$activity_log'
            }
      }}]
)
```

Comment: I think the above way is correct pymongo is triggering ```in validate_is_mapping
    raise TypeError("%s must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or "
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or any other type that inherits from collections.Mapping```

Comment: The pipeline form of update as added in MongoDB 4.2.  If the version of pymongo you are using doesn't support that in the `update` function, you might be able to run the [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/index.html#update) database command using [db.command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27298423/2282634)