# Call Mongodb Native Methods using Pymongo

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, pymongo

I will preface by saying that I am a novice in both Python and MongoDB.

I am developing a Python script that connects to a Linux Server with an instance of MongoDB and retrieves MongoDB's configuration information.  To do this, I have been using Pymongo.  For example, here is what I have used to retrieve the "authorization" parameter.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient(dbhost, int(dbport))
db['admin'].authenticate(dbuser,dbpass)

output = db['admin'].command("getCmdLineOpts")
```

This is equivalent to running the following command in the mongo shell on the server itself.

```
db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts")
```

The output looks something like this:

```
{
        "argv" : [
                "/usr/bin/mongod",
                "-f",
                "/etc/mongod.conf"
        ],
        "parsed" : {
                "auditLog" : {
                        "destination" : "file",
                        "filter" : "{ atype: { $in: [ \"createCollection\", \"dropCollection\" ] } }",
                        "format" : "JSON",
                        "path" : "/var/log/mongodb/auditlog.json"
                },
                "config" : "/etc/mongod.conf",
                "net" : {
                        "port" : 27017
                },
                "processManagement" : {
                        "fork" : true,
                        "pidFilePath" : "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid",
                        "timeZoneInfo" : "/usr/share/zoneinfo"
                },
                "security" : {
                        "authorization" : "enabled",
                        "clusterAuthMode" : "keyFile",
                        "javascriptEnabled" : false,
                        "keyFile" : "/var/lib/mongo/keyfile"
                },
                "setParameter" : {
                        "enableLocalhostAuthBypass" : "false"
                },
                "storage" : {
                        "dbPath" : "/var/lib/mongo",
                        "journal" : {
                                "enabled" : true
                        }
                },
                "systemLog" : {
                        "destination" : "file",
                        "logAppend" : true,
                        "path" : "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log",
                        "quiet" : false
                }
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I have then been able to parse out the parameter I need.  For example, to get the audit Log path:

```
auditLogPath = output['parsed']['auditLog']['path']
```

which is equivalent to running this in the mongo shell

```
db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts").parsed.auditLog.path
```

This code works fine, but I am stuck trying to find an equivalent PyMongo command for the Mongo shell native methods. By native methods, this is what I mean https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-native/.

Specifically, I am trying to read the mongod.service file and report on the parameters in the file.  In the mongo shell I can run the following command and receive the contents of the file at that location.

```
cat("/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service")
```

I am wondering if there is a way to run these native methods (such as ls or cat), in Pymongo, using some similar structure to

```
db.command(<commandName>)
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

`getCmdLineOpts` is a [server command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/).

You can issue it as any other command by running `{getCmdLineOpts:1}`, and it is my understanding that pymongo permits specifying command name only ([How to run raw mongodb commands from pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297727/how-to-run-raw-mongodb-commands-from-pymongo)) so you could potentially do

```
db.command("getCmdLineOpts")
```

Shell native methods only exist in the shell. They do not exist on the server and they are not implemented by pymongo. Python equivalent of `cat` is something like

```
open('/path/to/file').read()
```

and for `ls` there is [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory).