# add roles to a user in mongodb via python (pymongo)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I need help in adding new roles to an existing user in mongo DB. I need the solution in Pymongo. I would appreciate your help

I tried using db._create_or_update_user()
db._create_or_update_user( "UserName","password", roles= [  {"role": "read", "db": "databbase"} ] )

But I am getting the error, Missing 2 required positional arguments, password and readonly

Comment: Check out [How to run raw mongodb commands from pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27297727/2282634), and [grantRolesToUser](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/grantRolesToUser/#grantrolestouser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "raw" mongodb command with pymongo. Like this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()

db = client.your_database_name

db.command("grantRolesToUser", "your_username", roles=["read"])
```

Comment: I used as above but got the below error-
pymongo.errors.operationFailure: "user" is not a valid argument to grantRolesToUser, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': '"user" is not a valid argument to grantRolesToUser'. 'code': 2, 'codeName': 'BadValue'}

Comment: I removed the keyword user and it worked

db.command("grantRolesToUser", "your_username", roles=["read"]))

Comment: My bad, I edit the answer. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helps you.