# Pymongo - Find primary/master node name in mongodb replica set

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm working on an API which requires the primary node's name from an mongodb replia set.

Is there a way to get the **name and ip of primary/master node** in a **replicaset** using the ***pymongo API***?

Or generally any way i could get that info from a **python program**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [hello](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/command/hello/#hello.primary) command.

It will return

> hello.primary
> A string in the format of "[hostname]:[port]" listing the current primary member of the replica set.

For running a database command in pymongo see [How to run raw mongodb commands from pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297727/how-to-run-raw-mongodb-commands-from-pymongo)